# Police Checking Service

Tags: communication

I have been asked to get a police check prior to being awarded an I.T. Dev Contract. I really want this job, but need to provide this check as soon as possible to. So my question where can i go to get a background check?

I'm in Australia and i can see that the Australian Federal Police Offer a police check via fax. I don't have a fax machine, how else can I get this check done quickly?

Any pointers really helpful thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually can get this done two ways:

The Australian Federal Police do provide a 'National Police Check' online, however this required you to download, print, sign and upload a document. Personally this process did take some time to deliver the police check.

Site: https://www.afp.gov.au/what-we-do/services/criminal-records/national-police-checks

This service can also be done quicker, without this download, print, sign and upload process via a third party provider. Site: https://www.nationalcrimecheck.com.au

Look up some reviews on this service before trying, goodluck :)

Comment: Checking out the second link, they have been experiencing longer delays according to their FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to address only a part of this question - the part about having a fax machine.  There are a ridiculous number of online fax services available.  Some are for sending only, and others are for both sending and receiving.  Determine your need, and do a Google search.